# CouchDB; PUT update via url rewrite returning: "invalid UTF-8 JSON"

Tags: couchdb

I can update my documents just fine via:

```
/_design/test/_update/user/dbf805bece7d468c4782fffaa5018680
```

but when i try and do so via

```
/_design/test/_rewrite/user/dbf805bece7d468c4782fffaa5018680
```

using this rewrite script:

```
{
           "from": ":type/:key",
           "to": "_update/:type/:key",
           "method": "PUT"
},
```

I get the error:

```
{"error":"bad_request","reason":"invalid UTF-8 JSON"}
```

the Json I'm passing is fine; the exact same json works when I don't go via _rewrite and I can also insert the same json using the rewriten url using POST.

**EDIT:**
Changing :key to * helped me fix this... but it that the correct solution?

Comment: Would you mind posting the CouchDB log entry for that query? Maybe it shows a clue. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem and found that quoting the query-key fixes it.

For example:

```
/_design/test/_rewrite/user/"dbf805bece7d468c4782fffaa5018680"
```

But, in my case, I'm using the `GET` method.